Clairaut's Differential Equation
I have a question about Clairaut's Differential Equation.
$y=xy'+\frac{1}{y'}$
What i had done:
$p=y'=\frac{dy}{dx}\implies dy=pdx$
$y=px+\frac{1}{p}$
$dy=pdx+xdp-\frac{dp}{p^2}$
...
$p=C$
$y=Cx+\frac{1}{C}$
I need found envelope to see the singular solution. Can someone help me?

As $dy=p,dx$, the equation $p^2x=1$ remains for $dp\ne 0$.

Alternatively, (i) differentiate the equation $y-Cx-\frac{1}{C}=0$ with respect to $C$, (ii) solve for $C$, and (iii) substitute the result in $y=Cx+\frac{1}{C}$.

@Gonçalo Sorry but can you write how i can do step (i)?

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial C}(y-Cx-1/C)=0\implies -x+1/C^2=0$$

It's not much harder to consider a general Clairaut differential equation,
$$y = x y_x + f(y_x) .$$
In our case, $f(u) = \frac1u$.
Differentiating and rearranging gives
$$[x + f'(y_x)] y_{xx} = 0 ,$$
so either
$$y_{xx} = 0 \qquad \textrm{or} \qquad x + f'(y_x) = 0.$$
The first equation implies that the solutions are linear, and substituting in the original equation gives that they are the linear functions of the form
$$y = C x + f(C) ,$$ $C \in \operatorname{dom} f$, which agrees with the result in our case. The equation $x + f'(y_x) = 0$ is separable and yields the singular solution. For $f(u) = \frac1u$, the equation is
$$x - \frac1{y_x^2} = 0,$$
and separating and integrating gives $$y = \pm 2 \sqrt x + K .$$ Then substituting in the original equation imposes $K = 0$, so the singular solution(s) are
$$y(x) = \pm 2 \sqrt x.$$
In the below plot, the red lines are typical solutions, and the blue parabola is the singular solution.

